# Appcelerator custom font helvetica

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-alloy

I'm trying to use a custom font in appcelerator alloy framework.
I have the following files:

**header.tss**

```
".headerButtonLabel": {
    color: '#5d5d5d',
    shadowOffset: {x: 1, y: 1},
    shadowColor: '#ffffff',
    font: {fontSize: 18, fontFamily: 'Helvetica Neue LT Std 77 Bold Condensed'},
    textAlign: 'left'
}
```

**header.xml**

```
<Button class="headerButton">
    <Label class="headerButtonLabel" text="Text button here"></Label>
</Button>
```

**tiapp.xml**

```
<ios>
<plist>
    <dict>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
        <array>
            <string>fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd.otf</string>
            <string>fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-BdCn.otf</string>
            <string>fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman.otf</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>        
</ios>
```

Fonts are stored in app/assets/fonts

I've attached those fonts [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B0uxgTBVT34QcnhVMlJqYmFVMWs&usp=sharing&tid=0B0uxgTBVT34QXzFOVkpMVEdXbE0)

When I'm opening `HelveticaNeueLTStd-BdCn.otf`, it appears with the following name `Helvetica Neue LT Std 77 Bold Condensed`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figure it out after all.

[example image of where you will find the right name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bvLR.png)

It seems that PostScript name from font book is the right name when you develop for IOS.

Comment: You can use the 'Family' if you only have one font in the same Family as the Titanium documentation states.  However, the PostScript name will always work and can differentiate between different styles of fonts in the same Family